# How can Auto loop same DropDownMenu in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm still developing the MVC Project. I want to  **Display** same **Dropdownmenu** like a loop. How can I do it? My dropdown menus are working, it's not a problem.

**View**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.ItemId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Itm, "ItemId", "ItemName"), "", new { Class = "form-control", title = "", style = "width:175px;height:30px; margin-top:6px;font-size:small;" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.ItemId)
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult myIndex(string A, int? Id, string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
{
    var objContext = new KnittingdbContext();
    if (A == "New")
    {
        myViewModel my = new myViewModel();
        ViewBag.Itm = objContext.Items.ToList();
        ViewData["my"] = my;
        ViewBag.Module = A;
        ViewBag.ItmList = objContext.Items;
    }
    else if (A == "Edit")
    {
        var objBlog = objContext.mys.First(a => a.myId == Id);
        ViewBag.Itm = new SelectList(objContext.Items, "ItemID", "ItemName", objBlog.ItemId);
        ViewBag.Module = A;
        ViewData["Emy"] = objBlog;
```

Comment: Not clear what you question is? What problems are you having. And why do you have `ViewBag.Itm = objContext.Items.ToList();` in one block and `ViewBag.Itm = new SelectList(objContext.Items, "ItemID", "ItemName", objBlog.ItemId);` in another (the second wont work with the `DropDownListFor()` method you have)

Comment: Im use the viewBag. im gettin the dropdown for data Item model. i want to display same drop down menu like a list

Comment: You have a view model. Why on earth are you using `ViewBag`? And what do you mean _display like a list_?

Comment: yeah i have a view model, multiple list, I want to show dropdown list data another text filed, iam code it, its work, how can do multiple dropdown? give me a example, Thanks for the advice

Comment: Sorry, impossible to understand what your wanting to do.

Comment: i want to show MultiSelectList

Comment: Then you need `@Html.ListBoxFor()`, but that binds to a property which is an array - e.g. `int[] SelectedItems` (not `int ItemId`)

Comment: Thanks sir, Im try this one :)

Comment: Thanks sir, Its working :)